# In an iphone app deleted cells are reused but have previous usage effect

Tags: ios

I am reusing the cells as usual in one of my iphone applications and i need to delete a cell.The problem which i get is when i try to delete the cell using the commitEditingStyle method I get a red button with horizontal line.i click on it.it becomes vertical and cell deletion is done.But when i scroll up or down I get some new cells with vertical lines in their red button.These lines should be horizontal..Can someone help me through this

Below is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath          
{
     EVSMyFilesTableViewCell *cell = (EVSMyFilesTableViewCell *)[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyFilesViewCell"];
     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[EVSMyFilesTableViewCell alloc]   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyFilesViewCell"] autorelease];
}
FileInfo *file = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setFileInfo:file];
[[cell textLabel] setText:file.FileName];
return cell;
```

}

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
      [self.deletedata : indexPath.row];  //deleting data
}
 }
```

Comment: Please also show where you do the deletion (your `deleteData` method)